# How we can add user under IAM in gcp through gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am not able to add user through cli under identity access management . so kindly help me for this issue.

Comment: What is the command? What is the error? What type of access/roles are you trying to grant `OR` are you trying to create a new user `OR` are you trying to add a user to the project? More details on exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Could you provide what exactly your are trying and what error message you are getting during this?

Comment: As the other community support member suggested, try the below mentioned gcloud command to [add the IAM policy binding](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding) for a project with [verbosity flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity). Provide the results here. The verbosity flag would give you more information about the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can add users (with binded roles) with the command below. Just assign your variables to PROJECT_ID, USER_EMAIL and ROLE (like roles/editor)

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member user:$USER_EMAIL --role $ROLE
```

Doc: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding